# JQuery if label contains this... do this

Tags: jquery, class, label

I have asp.net repeater on a page. If each item being repeated is wrapped in a label like so:

```
<label class="ItemName">value</label>
```

If this label contains the text '35' I want to display some text next to it. How can i do this using jquery???

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('.ItemName').val().indexOf("35")) {
            $(this).val() = $(this).val() + "some text";
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The `this` in the `.ready` function should refer to the `document`.
2. To get the text content, use `.text()` instead of `.val()`.
3. To update some value, use `$obj.val(blah);`, not `$obj.val() = blah;`. (This is actually a limitation of Javascript.)
4. There is a [`:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to filter elements containing some text.
5. To append some text (or HTML), there is already [an `.append()` method](http://api.jquery.com/append/) (Thanks @J-P for reminding this.)

You may want this instead:

```
$('.ItemName:contains(35)').append("some text");
```

Comment: Very jQuery'ish! ;) ... what's wrong with `$(this).append()` (probably a tad faster than using the fancy `.text()` callback)?

Comment: the `x` is the index in your example, should be: `$('.ItemName:contains(35)').text(function(i, x) { return x + "some text"; });`

Answer (score 1):

`.text()` should work:

```
var item = $('.ItemName');
if ( item.text().indexOf("35") > -1 ) {
    item.after("some text");
}
```

Comment: i dont want all the labels to have the text after just the ones that have that text. I think here its detecting whether any have that text/

Comment: This solved my problem... to check if the label has "Not Available", then do something. so i used it like this `if ( item.text().indexOf("Not Available") > -1 ) { //remove radio button, add class to the label and add disabled attribute }`. Thanks @James

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` returns -1 if not found, or the index. Do this:

```
if ($('.ItemName').val().indexOf("35") >= 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

this you mean?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        if ($('.ItemName').text().indexOf("35")) {
            $(this).text($(this).text() + "some text");
        }
    });
```