# If element is not present on page why is JavaScript throwing an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My scenario is that I have one JS file which is being used on two HTML pages. One has a `button` with `id="a"` and the other doesn't have it. I have attached an event on `id="a"` by doing this.

```
document.getElementbyId("a").onclick = function () { .. }
```

My problem is when I run second file which doesn't have the `button` with `id="a"` and it throws the error

```
TypeError: document.getElementbyId(...) is null
```

which causes some unexpected behaviour! Is there any way to keep using just one JS file or should I separate the JS file for every html page?

I read a question on StackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709604/why-doesnt-jquery-bomb-if-your-selector-object-is-invalid) which is about why jQuery doesn't throw an error if the selector is invalid. I need same or similar functionality with vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: jQuery silently ignores "element not found" conditions because sometimes you want that behaviour and sometimes you don't. Personally, if I say "find this element" and "this element" doesn't exist, I *want* an error...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simple fix is to add a check:

```
if (document.getElementById("a") !== null) {
    document.getElementById("a").onclick = function () /* .. */ };
}
```

jQuery will never break on missing elements, it just silently fails. You can argue about whether that is good or not.

The trick jQuery uses is that it will always return something. `$("#id")` will return a jQuery wrapper. That wrapper has functions like `.on` and `.load` and `.html`. A selector can match one, more or no elements. For the wrapper it doesn't matter how many elements are matched.

It works like this:

```
var elem = get_element("a");
elem.onclick(callback);

function get_element(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    return { // return a wrapper
        onclick: function (callback) {
            if (elem !== null) {
                elem.onclick = callback;
            } else {
                // silently fail
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Should be `getElementById()` - you've picked up the OP's miscapitalization.

Comment: In your fix, do you need the " !== null" part? Or can you just do:
if (document.getElementById("a"))
{ document.getElementById("a").onclick = function () /* .. */ }; } 
?

Answer (score 4):

Consider testing existance

```
var elm = document.getElementById("a");
if (elm) elm.onclick = function () { .. };
```

Or falling back in the case of a falsy

```
(document.getElementById("a") || {}).onclick = function () { .. };
```

In this second method, the function still gets set but will be quickly GC'd as the reference to `{}` dies by the next line.

Answer (score 4):

All of the above solutions are correct.  However, you should definitely move away from writing `whatever.onclick = function` as that is no longer the best way to write your code.  Using this method, you only get one click event.  Using a more modern approach allows you to attach as many events as you want.

Also, you mention jQuery but there is no jQuery in the supplied code only vanilla JavaScript.  Do you need a jQuery solution or JavaScript?

#### JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  var elm = document.getElementById('a');
  if ( elm ) { //if the element exists add the click event
    elm.addEventListener('click', function(){
      //Your "onclick" code here
    });
  }
});
```

#### jQuery

```
$(function(){
  $('#a').on('click', function(){
    //Your "onclick" code here
  });
});
```